# Azure app service continuous integration MSI Error 400

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service

When I deploy .net core app to Azure app service and enable continuous integration, I get error "Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request"[image]

Comment: Which option you have chosen for build ?

Comment: I added .net core job (tasks) and it automatically added, NuGet 4.4.1 installer, NuGet restore, build solution, azure app service deploy, publish symbols path and publish artifacts: drop